# Creating a button that redirects to another page in HTML

Tags: html, redirect, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down menu in HTML that has a list of all 50 states. Example:

```
<select>
<option value="AL">Alabama</option>
</select>
```

I am wanting to have a "Go" button next to it that redirects to a page with the selected state. Is this possible in HTML? How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible. What you want to achieve requires an anchor tag on every option. I've tried that but only the option gets clicked.